# how sort a vector list using collecton frameworks java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, vector

I am trying to sort a `Vector` list using the Java Collections frameworks.

This is my code...

```
public class RiverList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<River> rivers = new Vector<River>();
        //name length and discharge

        River river3 = new River("Nil", 6852, 2660);
        River river5 = new River("Amazonas", 6448, 209000);
        River river1 = new River("Rhein", 1233, 2330);
        River river4 = new River("Donau", 2857, 6700);
        River river2 = new River("Oker", 128, 12);

        rivers.add(river1);
        rivers.add(river2);
        rivers.add(river3);
        rivers.add(river4);
        rivers.add(river5);

        System.out.println(rivers);

        // sort the river after length with help class collection

        System.out.println(rivers);

        // sort the river after discharge with help class collection

        System.out.println(rivers);
    }
}

public class River {
    private int length;
    private int discharge;
    private String name; 

    public River(String name, int length, int discharge) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.discharge = discharge;
    }

    // getters and setters
    ...

    public String toString() {
        return name + ", Length = " + length + ", discharge = " + discharge + "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is what I have done, but I am stuck on how to proceed further...

```
public class RiverLengthComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class RiverDischargeComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The output should be like this (for river length)...

```
("Nil", 6852, 2660);
("Amazonas", 6448, 209000);
("Donau", 2857, 6700);
("Rhein", 1233, 2330);
("Oker", 128, 12);
```

And for river discharge...

```
("Amazonas", 6448, 209000);
("Donau", 2857, 6700);
("Nil", 6852, 2660);
("Rhein", 1233, 2330);
("Oker", 128, 12);
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: In the future, I'd suggest using `ArrayList`. Never use `Vector`. Someone correct me if I'm wrong: Vectors are synchronized while `ArrayLists` are not (?)

Comment: if this is homework, please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: @fireshadow52 according to the documentation: yes.

Comment: sorry i dont know about thet, i will keep in mind in the future thanks a lot

Comment: @fireshadow52 Whats wrong when it is synchronized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe your `compare` method should return something else than `0` ;)
Think about what you want to achieve and read the documentation of the `Comparator` interface.

maybe using `Comparator<River>` instead of just `Comparator` would be a first step.

In the end you might want to use `Collections.sort(rivers, new RiverLengthComparator());` with the comparator you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(vector);
```

BTW What do you get from these print statements??

```
System.out.println(rivers);

//sort the river after length with help class colection

System.out.println(rivers);

//sort the river after discharge with help class colection


System.out.println(rivers);
```

Comment: I think instead of the comments the OP is searching for the sorting command you provided. but I think he wants to use his custom comparators rather than the default `sort` method

Comment: if you run the program you should have the three sorted list, the second println sort after length of the river and the third one sort after discharge of the river